# What do you call a place where a shell lands?

Tags: phrase-request

What do you call a place where a shell lands? 'A site of attack'? 'Targeted area'? I don't like the latter because it implies the shell landed exactly where it was supposed to (which is not always the case).

Comment: The landing place of an artillery shell is often called its **impact point** or **point of impact** in discussions related to trajectories and their calculation, fall of shell distribution, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The landing place of an artillery shell is often called its impact point or point of impact in discussions related to trajectories and their calculation, fall of shell distribution, etc. – Michael Harvey